# Is it possible to target Android 28 (eg`targetSdkVersion 28`) and use both appcompat-v7 and Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, android-support-library, android-appcompat

Has anyone managed to target Android 28 (eg set `targetSdkVersion 28`) and use Firebase? My build.gradle is as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.example.fireeats"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Android Studio warns of mixed versions: `Found versions 28.0.0-rc02, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc02 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0`

[image: Android Studio Warning]
Is Firebase 16.0.3 incompatible with the Android 28 support lib?

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing, Firebase depends on the support library versions 27 so you do need to provide explicit overrides. See the working build file below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.example.fireeats"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0' // NEED TO ADD
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' //NEED TO ADD
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```